# Update PWA with firebase

Tags: javascript, firebase, progressive-web-apps, firebase-hosting

I made a progressive web application with firebase hosting. When I do some changes and I deploy I don't see the changes when I visit the app from browser.

This is my code in sw.js:

```
self.addEventListener('install', function (event) {
  console.log('SW Installed');
  event.waitUntil(
    caches.open('static')
      .then(function (cache) {
        cache.addAll([
          '/',
          '/index.html',
          '/app.js',
          '/images/icons/icon-144x144.png'
        ]);
      })
  );
});

self.addEventListener('activate', function () {
  console.log('SW Activated');
});

self.addEventListener('fetch', function(event) {
  event.respondWith(
    caches.match(event.request)
      .then(function(res) {
        if (res) {
          return res;
        } else {
          return fetch(event.request);
        }
      })
  );
});
```

This is my code in firebase.json:

```
{
  "hosting": {
    "public": "public"
  }
}
```

Comment: Would be better if you post some code of your *firebase.json* file and your *service worker*, until then hard to say what's happening here.

Comment: Ok, I have added the code of firebase.json.

Answer (score 7):

Your `sw.js` file is caching your app's assets to a cache called `static`.

```
caches.open('static')
  .then(function (cache) {
    cache.addAll([
      '/',
      '/index.html',
      '/app.js',
      '/images/icons/icon-144x144.png'
    ]);
  })
```

When you redeploy your Firebase Hosting app this cache isn't cleared so you wont see any changes.

In the Developer Tools in chrome, you'll be able to see the **Cache** section which will list your cache (the one in the screenshot below is called `offline`)

From here, you can right-click and select `Delete` to clear it.

[image: Cache example]

Alternatively you can just run...

```
caches.delete("static");
```

In your console to delete the cache (or add a button in your app to "Load a new version") which clears the cache and refreshes the page.

Comment: I want install in smartphone and I want that the app can update automatically if there is new content. Where I must insert 
caches.delete("static"); ?

Comment: Take a look at this chapter https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/building-progressive-web/9781491961643/ch04.html it covers a lot of information about the PWA lifecycle and cache management. The short version if you'll need to watch the status of Service Workers and automatically clean up the old cache when a new Service Worker is detected (often after a refresh or two). So yes it's doable, but it's a bit clunky as a developer.

Answer (score 0):

While working on a similar issue, I found this tutorial helpful: [link](https://redfin.engineering/how-to-fix-the-refresh-button-when-using-service-workers-a8e27af6df68). My application is only for mobile apps so I went with approach #2. It worked for me -- such that refreshing the page a few times eventually updated the installed PWA.

This involved adding `skipWaiting()` to the start of my service worker script (ie `sw.js`).

Then putting this code in the main html page (ie `index.html`, probably)

```js
  // handles page refresh service worker update
  var refreshing;
  navigator.serviceWorker.addEventListener('controllerchange',
    function () {
      if (refreshing) return;
      refreshing = true;
      window.location.reload();
    }
  );
```